# hilasterion as a mercy seat

Tags: romans, hebrews, paul

Many have attempted to say that the *hilasterion* is a 'mercy seat' but the word *ilios* does not mean 'mercy'. That word is *eleos*. Strong 1656. What does this *Ilios* mean and how does it differ from *hilasterion*? I know that the term propitiation is a specialized term used in English.

Romans 3:25 KJV

> Whom God hath set forth to be a **propitiation** through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;

1 John 2:1-2 KJV

> <sup>**1**</sup> My little children, these things write I unto you, that ye sin not. And if any man sin, we have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous: <sup>**2**</sup> And he is the **propitiation** for our sins: and not for ours only, but also for the sins of the whole world.

Hebrews 9:5

> And over it the cherubims of glory shadowing the **mercyseat**; of which we cannot now speak particularly.

Comment: I agree with you. Up-voted. _Ilios_ is a matter of composure. Its usage in the New Testament writings is clear from how Peter uses it 'Contain thyself' as he says to the Lord. The hilasterion represents the composure of God due to the containment of sin. I have researched the word and I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is correct that the words often translated "mercy seat" (meaning the lid for the Ark of the Covenant) means nothing of the kind.  So, why do most English translations translate them thus in the NT, instead of the more accurate, "propitiation sacrifice" or similar (which NONE actually do.

The reason is old and complex but is equally true in the OT.  So let us begin there.

In Ex 25:20, we find the first mention of the "mercy seat" (so called) which is translated from the Hebrew סָכַךְ (chakak) meaning, "to cover".  This was literally true in two important ways:

- the lid of the Ark of the Covenant was a covering for the box!
- the lid was a covering for the law of 10 commandments which the box contained, Ex 40:20.

Further, by comparison with the several theophanies in the OT (eg, Eze 1, Isa 6) it becomes clear that the Ark of the Covenant was a symbol of the throne of God.  Thus, when God dispensed judgement but heavily slanted toward forgiveness and kindness, the Cover of the Ark of the Covenant also became known as "The Mercy Seat."  Indeed, Heb 4;16 calls God's throne, the "Throne of Grace".

Now, as mentioned above, the original language in the Hebrew and Greek does not indicate "mercy", but propitiation by covering of sin and the covering of the law!  Thus, without defending the highly interpretive translation of "mercy seat", it is historically understandable.

Despite the above, a few conspicuous versions correctly translate the Hebrew in places like Ex 25:20, 21 as "cover" or similar such as: NIV, NLT, NASB, Brenton (of LXX), CEV, etc.

Answer (score 2):

All of the below is taken from my book '*The Cherubim of Glory*' pp56-62 all of which book is available, free of charge, on my website. See my profile for the link to my website.

---

The word *hilasterion* does not convey the Greek word for mercy, *eleos*; the word *hilasterion* is derived from *hilaros* which in turn is derived from *hilews*. And
*hilews* does not mean ‘mercy’. The w is omega, the last letter of the Greek alphabet and is a long ‘o’, as in ‘post’ rather than a short ‘o’ as in ‘stop’.

The word *hilews* :

1. Matthew 16:22 *Hilews* to thee, Lord. In no wise shall this be to
   thee.
2. Hebrews 8:12 I will be *hilews* to their unrighteousness.

The word *hilaros*:
3. II Corinthians 9:7 God loveth a *hilaros* giver.

The word *hilarotes*:
4. Romans 12:8 He that showeth mercy with *hilarotes*
5. I John 2:2 He is the *hilasmos* for our sins
6. I John 4:10 His Son, to be the *hilasmos* for our sins

The word *hilaskomai:*
7. Luke 18:13 God be hilaskomai, to me, a sinner.
8. Hebrews 2:17 Make *hilaskomai* for the sins of the people.

The word *hilasterion*:
9. Romans 3:25 A *hilasterion*, through faith in his blood.
10. Hebrews 9:5 Cherubim of glory, shadowing the *hilasterion.*

It is plainly evident that, regarding the word *hilasterion*, two root
words are important:
a. *Hilews*
b. *Stereos*

There is, indeed, a difficulty. The difficulty is to perceive exactly
what *hilews* means. I grant, the word *eleos* is much easier. But
that is no excuse for substituting it into the English translation
where it does not belong. Any more than is substituting the
unhelpful wording ‘make an atonement’ for the verb *kathar* and,
also, for the plural expression *kippurim.*

*Stereos* is quite obvious. There is no excuse for attempting to call
this a ‘seat’. *Stereoma* and sterigmos are both translated
‘steadfastness’; *stereoo* is rendered ‘establish, make strong,
receive strength’; sterizo is given as ‘establish, fix, set steadfastly,
stablish and strengthen’; *stereos* itself is represented as
‘steadfast, strong and sure’. This collection of words is used
twenty two times in the Greek scripture and in every case, they
are accepted as meaning, overall, ‘strong and steadfast’. That is,
something has strength and because of that strength, it does not
move.

The main - and, indeed, the only - feature of a ‘seat’ is - that it is a
place to sit upon. There is no other feature to a seat. A ‘seat’
could be an upturned log temporarily placed there to - sit upon.
References to the kapporeth in the Hebrew are that God dwells
between the cherubim. And that God will meet with men there.
From between the cherubim, from above the *kapporeth*, is the
dwelling of almighty God. That is what the Hebrew conveys by
the wording me-al in both Exodus 25:22 and in Numbers 7:89.
Me-al conveys ‘from above’. But both the AV and Robert Young
have translated the prepositions as ‘from off’ the ‘mercy seat’.
There is nothing at all within the word *kapporeth* which would
convey that it is a seat. Nor does *me-al* convey ‘from’ ‘off’. Not
that ‘from off’ sounds like proper English to me, in any case.

The Septuagint in those two places translates *me-al* with the
Greek *anothen*. In Greek scripture, *anothen* is rendered in
English ‘from above’, generally, or sometimes ‘from the
beginning’ or ‘from the first’, or simply ‘the top’. *Anoteron* is
‘above’ or ‘higher’ and *anoterikos* is ‘upper’. My impression is
that translators rendering *me-al* as ‘from off’ are interpreting,
not translating.

It is clear to me that they are insisting on the idea of a seat and in
order to do it, they are forcing both Hebrew and English to mean
what they do not mean. God is a spirit, I must point out. And, to
me, the ark, complete with *kapporeth*, is a coffer, not a sedan
62 chair. Rightly seen, the coffer ends in the sepulchre where one
was at the head and one at the feet and they said, He is not here,
he is risen.

The Everlasting Testament, of which the ark and the *kapporeth*
and the *kerubim* testify, requires a Testator. And the Everlasting
Testament cannot be initiated until the death of the Testator. It
is prevented from operating until the death of the Testator. See,
‘*The Everlasting Testament*’, Belmont Publications.